# 'weexpack run web' throwing error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, weex

I've installed a weexpack project.

When I am trying to run the command weexpack run web It's showing error.

```
module.js:442
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../src/run/Web'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. (/home/dev03/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/weexpack/bin/weexpack-run:7:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: I'm curious about this too... I'm seeing that same exact error with `weex run`, `weex run web`, _and_ `weex run android`.

Comment: @codermonkeyfuel Its actually path/case sensitive problem.

Error: Cannot find module '../src/run/Web'

./src/run/web  => here 'W' will be 'w'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @zahidul-islam-suzon in the comment above, it looks like this is a case sensitivity bug in `weexpack`: https://github.com/weexteam/weex-pack/issues/148#issuecomment-302861410

It can be fixed by renaming `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/weexpack/src/run/web.js` (or wherever your `weexpack` is installed) to `Web.js`.